# SVG element onClick event with z index

Tags: svg, vega

I have an svg element overlaid on top of a vega plot. The svg element has the following style properties:

```
pointerEvents: 'none',
zIndex: 1
```

Becuase of the `pointerEvents: 'none'`, it can't respond to the mouse event. I have some on click events that respond to some mouse movement on specific elements on the vega plot. The overlaid svg element is just a small portion of the vega plot. If I comment out the `pointerEvents` line, the svg element becomes responsive but the vega plot becomes unresponsive. How to use `onClick` event when there are two elements with relative positions and have them both be responsive?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

When you put a book on  a table and click the book, the table is not clicked.

You can use `elementsFromPoint( x , y )` to get an array of all elements **under** the click point.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint